# How to host Rest API server in Android application using Jersey?

Tags: android, web-services, server, jersey

I want to host Rest API server on an Android device without using iJetty can someone tell me how to achieve this using Jersey?

Is there any android library available in Jersey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer https://github.com/skornei/restserver see the steps https://github.com/skornei/restserver/wiki/Getting-started

This worked for me. Thanks